# How to deal with ties to fit data into continuous distributions in R?

Tags: r, continuous-data

I have rainfall duration and volume data. the duration is `t=2  3  2  2  2  2  3  2  2  3  2  1  2  4 14  6  4  4  5  4  3  4  6  4  8  3  3  2  2  3  7  3 11  2  1  6  2  9  5  4  5  3  2  3  8  5  3  2  3  1  4  2  2  1  3  8 13  7  2  3  3  2  8  3  5  3  7  1  4  3  3  3 24  3  4  7  3  3 13  2  3  6  2  4 10  2  2  3  3  9 24  4  3  4  4  5 12  5  6  3  4  5  3  4  3  7  4  3  3  3  4  4  9  3 16 11  4  2  9  3  6  5  3  3  6  6  6  5  4  3  3  3  4  8  7  4  4  3  4  2  5  6 10  4  2  3  1 12  3  4  3  5  2  4  3  7  7  2  2  3  5  2  4  6  4  4  7  9 20 10  2  2 10  6  6  2  3 10  2  5  7  3  5  5  3  4  1  2  3  5  2  3  6  2  2  5  8  5 12  3  4  2  4 10  2  4  1  5  2  3  4  2  2  8 10  6  4  2  7  3  4  4  3  3  3  5  4  5  2  4  4  3  2  4  2  3  6  3  2  5  2  3  4  7  4  3  5  4  2  5  4  2  2  3  5  5`

I wanna ask if I can construct pseudo-observations by randomly breaking ties?

`pseudot <- sapply(t, rank, ties.method = "random") / + (nrow(t) + 1)`

Under the assumption of the data is continuous, can I do this way to deal with ties? I want to fit the data into a few continuous distributions and then fit the estimation data into Copula

Paper that I refer to: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v034i09

Comment: tie for continuous is zero. For descrite with copula is difficult. For continuous, just have a look to pobs() in copula backage

Comment: With many ties, the random breaking is going to screw up the copula badly unless it's already an independence copula.  It is likely that a better approach would be to adopt a multivariate model, perhaps separately parameterizing the two marginals and a copula family, and then treat these as *interval-valued* data to estimate the model parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You've asked whether you *can* do this -- sure, nobody can stop you.

Your real question is probably: is this a good idea? **I don't think so.** I'd feel comfortable using an approach like this to break a *few* ties, but you don't have a *few* ties, you have a data set built almost entirely out of ties. If there are (for instance) 20 instances of the number 2, then you have 20!, or about 2 quintillion, ways to break those ties, and you're choosing one at random. This choice could be hugely consequential, though, depending on the way that the data are linked to the other variables in the same observations. Since you've only provided this column, it's impossible to know whether this is an actual problem or a theoretical problem, but given the tremendous number of ties in what you've got, I'd be rather suspicious of breaking ties in this way.

Of course, the fact that you're interested in ties at all suggests you're doing something that's suitable for ordinal-level data -- that is, you want to know which numbers are bigger than others. You've said you want to assume that these data are continuous, so you might shop around for an alternate way to solve whatever your problem is that really *uses* continuous data; OLS (ordinary least-squares) regression or logistic regression are two very common examples that would be safer to use on these data *without* resorting to any strategy correcting ties.

Short answer: I'd suggest *not* to break ties in this way and instead to shop for a method that avoids tiebreaking altogether.